# How to print a value with double quotes and spaces in YAML?

Tags: yaml, python-3.5, pyyaml

I am trying to dump a Python dictionary to YAML which has some strings as value fields.

```
import yaml
str1 = "hello"
str2 = "world"
mystr = "\"" + str1 + str(" ") + str2 + "\""
mydict = {"a" : mystr}
f = open("temp.yaml", "w")
yaml.dump(mydict, f, default_flow_style = False, \
                    explicit_start = "---", explicit_end = "...", encoding = 'UTF-8')
f.close()
```

the YAML I get is:

```
a: '"hello
 world"'
```

Notice, the value "hello world" is spilling to the next line.
I am using python 3.5 and YAML module version is 3.11

Can someone tell me how to make the YAML look like below?

```
a: "hello world"
```

Comment: 1. You probably want to dump `mydict` instead of `mystr`. 2. I'm getting `{a: '"hello world"'}` with python 3.5.3 and pyyaml 3.12. Are you sure you are showing the real code you are using?

Comment: 3. If you want to output values with double quotes, you have to tell that PyYAML (sorry, don't know currently if there is an option for that). Adding doublequotes to your string before dumping will not have the desired effect, as you can see from my output `{a: '"hello world"'}`

Comment: @tinita : yes i am dumping 'mydict' not 'mystr' ...edited it above... i could see the a single quote in front of the double quote too...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is a bit sloppy but it will give the results you want.

```
global dict_keys

def mk_double_quote(dumper, data):
    if data in dict_keys:
        return dumper.represent_scalar('tag:yaml.org,2002:str', data, style='')
    else:
        return dumper.represent_scalar('tag:yaml.org,2002:str', data, style='"')

yaml.add_representer(str, mk_double_quote)

d = {'a': 'Hello World'}
dict_keys = set(d.keys())

f = open('temp.yaml', 'w')
yaml.dump(d, f, default_flow_style=False, encoding='utf-8')
f.close()
```

The result will look like: `a: "Hello World"`

Answer (score 2):

If you want fine grain control over which string gets double (or single) quotes, you should use [ruamel.yaml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml) (disclaimer: I am the author of that package). It is an improved version of PyYAML, with many longstanding issues in PyYAML fixed.

With it you can do:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

mystr = ruamel.yaml.scalarstring.DoubleQuotedScalarString('hello world')
mydict = dict(a=mystr)

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.dump(mydict, sys.stdout)
```

to get:

```
a: "hello world"
```

If you start out with a YAML document, things are even easier, you can just indicate you want to preserve these superfluous quotes:

```
yaml_str = """\
a: "hello world"
"""

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```