# Python 3.5 - How to print a value with double quotes in YAML?

Tags: yaml, python-3.5, double-quotes, ruamel.yaml

I wanted to print a YAML file (with keys and values) and with some values between double quotes.
I wanted to use the solution provide here: [How to print a value with double quotes and spaces in YAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47542343/how-to-print-a-value-with-double-quotes-and-spaces-in-yaml)

Unfortunately when I installed ruamel.yaml for python 3.5 (`sudo apt install python3-ruamel.yaml`) I was not able to find the function DoubleQuotedScalarString() in the script scalarstring.py .
Here is what it looks like:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import print_function

__all__ = ["ScalarString", "PreservedScalarString"]

try:
    from .compat import text_type
except (ImportError, ValueError):  # for Jython
    from ruamel.yaml.compat import text_type


class ScalarString(text_type):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kw):
        return text_type.__new__(cls, *args, **kw)


class PreservedScalarString(ScalarString):
    def __new__(cls, value):
        return ScalarString.__new__(cls, value)


def preserve_literal(s):
    return PreservedScalarString(s.replace('\r\n', '\n').replace('\r', '\n'))


def walk_tree(base):
    """
    the routine here walks over a simple yaml tree (recursing in
    dict values and list items) and converts strings that
    have multiple lines to literal scalars
    """
    from ruamel.yaml.compat import string_types

    if isinstance(base, dict):
        for k in base:
            v = base[k]
            if isinstance(v, string_types) and '\n' in v:
                base[k] = preserve_literal(v)
            else:
                walk_tree(v)
    elif isinstance(base, list):
        for idx, elem in enumerate(base):
            if isinstance(elem, string_types) and '\n' in elem:
                print(elem)
                base[idx] = preserve_literal(elem)
            else:
                walk_tree(elem)
```

Currently this is what I obtain when using ruamel.yamp.dump() to get my yaml file:

```
key1: 0,0,0,0
key2: 0,0,0,0
```

And here is what I would like in my yaml file:

```
key1: "0,0,0,0"
key2: "0,0,0,0"
```

How am I suppose to solve this?

Comment: May I ask why you need this to be quoted?

Comment: @tinita : I would like my yaml file to be understood the same way as a json file.
unfortunately when using a converter where I can check which format would have a json file from the yaml file I have, if the value 0,0,0,0 is written like this in YAML, when converted in JSON it is understood as 0.
it is only understood correctly when adding the quotes "0,0,0,0" --> in JSON giving "0,0,0,0" which is what I expect to obtain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **class** `DoubleQuotedScalarString` was added 2016-07-06.

You should update your version of `ruamel.yaml` e.g. using pip install -U ruamel.yaml. You can see what version you have by looking at the `__init__.py` in the `yaml` directory. The current version (June 2018) has:

```
version_info=(0, 15, 37),
```

In general it is best not to install additional python packages under Linux, using the package manager. Instead create a virtualenv for each program you want to develop and install all packages necessary for that program in such a virtualenv.

Answer (score 0):

So I found a quick and dirty solution to complete Anthon's answer:
First of all, Anthon is right I should work in a virtual environment. With my current app, I was lazy, so I didn't, that's a mistake.
I found that `sudo apt install python3-ruamel.yaml` was not installing the package in the same dir than `sudo pip3 install ruamel.yaml`.
The package versions are also not the same which is the reason why I got confused.
Here is the quick and dirty solution that worked for me:
copy all ".py" files from the source (https://pypi.org/project/ruamel.yaml/#files) inside the dir where your ruamel.yaml package is installed (/my/default/python3-lib/ruamel/yaml/) with e.g. `mv /home/user/Downloads/ruamel.yaml-0.15.38/*.py /my/default/python3-lib/ruamel/yaml/`
It solved the problem for me. 
As Anthon already answered, the clean solution is to use a virtual env.

Comment: I am a bit surprised this worked for you. I would have expected that you needed `representer.py` as well. If you do this you should probably copy all the .py files. But beware: depending on the version number differences you might break some package that is relying on the distribution provided package.

Comment: @Anthon once again you are right, I am editing the answer now. Thanks!